# How to add timedelta on a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to add a timedelta of 1 hour to a subset of my dataframe. I use `df['2022-06-01 02:00:00':'2022-06-01 04:00:00']` to slice it and add `+ pd.Timedelta(hours=1)` but I get an error.

I want to add a timedelta only on `2022-06-01 02:00:00':'2022-06-01 04:00:00'. How can I achieve that? Solution can be either as datetime as index or as column.

This is the datetime in the dataframe:

```
2022-06-01 00:30:00, 
2022-06-01 01:00:00,
2022-06-01 01:30:00, 
2022-06-01 02:00:00,
2022-06-01 02:30:00, 
2022-06-01 03:00:00,
2022-06-01 03:30:00,
2022-06-01 04:00:00,
2022-06-01 04:30:00,
2022-06-01 05:00:00,
2022-06-01 05:30:00,
2022-06-01 06:00:00,
2022-11-16 06:30:00,
2022-11-16 07:00:00,
2022-11-16 07:30:00, 
2022-11-16 08:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions for `DatetimeIndex`:

You can create mask and rename values of index by [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html):

```
mask = (df.index >= '2022-06-01 02:00:00') & (df.index <= '2022-06-01 04:00:00')
df.index = df.index.where(~mask, df.index + pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
```

Or get indices and use [`DataFrame.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) by dictionary:

```
i = df['2022-06-01 02:00:00':'2022-06-01 04:00:00'].index

df = df.rename(dict(zip(i, i + pd.Timedelta(hours=1))))
```

Solutions for `date` column:

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for boolean mask and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set new values:

```
mask = df['date'].between('2022-06-01 02:00:00','2022-06-01 04:00:00')

df.loc[mask, 'date'] += pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

Or [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].mask(mask, df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
```